# Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :

Tags: r, linux, parallel-processing, bioinformatics

I am currently running an ensemble niche model analyses through a Linux cluster in a CentOs6 environment. The package I am using is `SSDM`. My code is as follows:

```
Env <- load_var(path = getwd(), files = NULL, format = c(".grd", ".tif", ".asc",
                                                     ".sdat", ".rst", ".nc", ".envi", ".bil", ".img"), categorical = "af_anthrome.asc",
            Norm = TRUE, tmp = TRUE, verbose = TRUE, GUI = FALSE)
Env
head(Env)
warnings()
Occurrences <- load_occ(path = getwd(), Env, file = 
"Final_African_Bird_occurrence_rarefied_points.txt", 
                    Xcol = "decimallon", Ycol = "decimallat", Spcol = 
"species", GeoRes = FALSE,
                    sep = ",", verbose = TRUE, GUI = FALSE)
head(Occurrences)
warnings()
SSDM <- stack_modelling(c("GLM", "GAM", "MARS", "GBM", "RF", "CTA", 
"MAXENT", "ANN", "SVM"), Occurrences, Env, Xcol = "decimallon",
                    Ycol = "decimallat", Pcol = NULL, Spcol = "species", rep 
 = 1,
                    name = "Stack", save = TRUE, path = getwd(), PA = NULL,
                    cv = "holdout", cv.param = c(0.75, 1), thresh = 1001,
                    axes.metric = "Pearson", uncertainty = TRUE, tmp = TRUE,
                    ensemble.metric = c("AUC", "Kappa", "sensitivity", "specificity"), ensemble.thresh = c(0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75), weight = TRUE,
                    method = "bSSDM", metric = "SES", range = NULL,
                    endemism = NULL, verbose = TRUE, GUI = FALSE, cores = 125)

 save.stack(SSDM, name = "Bird", path = getwd(),
       verbose = TRUE, GUI = FALSE)
```

When running the `stack_modelling` function I get this Error message:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
125 nodes produced errors; first error: comparison of these types is not 
implemented
Calls: stack_modelling ... clusterApply -> staticClusterApply -> 
checkForRemoteErrors
In addition: Warning message:
In stack_modelling(c("GLM", "GAM", "MARS", "GBM", "RF", "CTA", "MAXENT",  :
It seems you attributed more cores than your CPU have !
Execution halted
Error in unserialize(node$con) : error reading from connection
Calls: <Anonymous> ... doTryCatch -> recvData -> recvData.SOCKnode -> 
unserialize
In addition: Warning message:
In eval(e, x, parent.frame()) :
Incompatible methods ("Ops.data.frame", "Ops.factor") for "=="
Execution halted
```

I understand that I may have attributed more cores than I have access to but this same error message crops up when I use a fraction of the cores. I am not entirely sure what this error message is trying to tell me or how to fix it as I am new to working on a cluster. Is it a problem with parallel processing of the data? Is there a line of code which can help me fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: The `Error in unserialize(node$con) : error reading from connection
Calls: <Anonymous> ... doTryCatch -> recvData -> recvData.SOCKnode -> 
unserialize` happens when communication between the main R process and one of the background R workers fails. The most likely reason for this is that the R worker crashed, which can happen if it runs out of memory or something serious such as a core dump has occurred.  It's unlikely due to regular programming errors.

Comment: Thank you Hendrik for clearing this up. Is there a command which I can use to diagnose the problem, ie. if it is an R worker which has crashed or whether there is a memory problem? Will `sessionInfo` give me this information?

Comment: I suspect the `Error in unserialize(node$con) : error reading from connection Calls: <Anonymous> ... doTryCatch -> recvData -> recvData.SOCKnode -> unserialize` is related to the initial `checkForRemoteErrors` message. However the message is not clear and when I try a `trace` function the error message is vague and does not tell me which line of code is wrong.